# audience_network.dex com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.89.A0E - Crashes on Android 10 after adding Meta Audience Network mediation adapter

Tags: android, admob, google-play-console, mobile-ad-mediation

I am experiencing a significant increase in crashes on Android 10 devices since adding the Meta Audience Network mediation adapter and these crashes are only being reported in the Google Play Console and not in Firebase Crashlytics, Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Similarly, the following crash is also reported.

`[libart.so] artQuickToInterpreterBridge`

**Stack Trace**

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 27202 >>> com.company.name <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x000000000053fe18  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::verifier::impl::(anonymous namespace)::MethodVerifier<false>::GetMethodReturnType()+92)
  #01  pc 0x000000000054c9b4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::verifier::impl::(anonymous namespace)::MethodVerifier<false>::CodeFlowVerifyInstruction(unsigned int*)+13732)
  #02  pc 0x000000000052fd20  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier4impl12_GLOBAL__N_114MethodVerifierILb0EE6VerifyEv$09bf97eb2c0d684adb6d215f7005036e+14328)
  #03  pc 0x000000000052b8c4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::verifier::MethodVerifier::FailureData art::verifier::MethodVerifier::VerifyMethod<false>(art::Thread*, unsigned int, art::DexFile const*, art::Handle<art::mirror::DexCache>, art::DexFile const*<art::Handle::ClassLoader>, art::dex::ClassDef const&, art::DexFile const*<art::Handle::ClassLoader>::CodeItem const*, art::ArtMethod*, unsigned int, art::CompilerCallbacks*, bool, art::verifier::HardFailLogMode, bool, unsigned int, std::__1::basic_string<char, art::verifier::HardFailLogMode::char_traits<char>, art::verifier::HardFailLogMode::allocator<char>>*)+260)
  #04  pc 0x0000000000529cc0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::verifier::ClassVerifier::VerifyClass(art::Thread*, art::DexFile const*, art::Handle<art::mirror::DexCache>, art::Handle<art::mirror::ClassLoader>, art::dex::ClassDef const&, art::CompilerCallbacks*, bool, art::verifier::HardFailLogMode, unsigned int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>*)+1316)
  #05  pc 0x000000000052955c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::verifier::ClassVerifier::VerifyClass(art::Thread*, art::ObjPtr<art::mirror::Class>, art::CompilerCallbacks*, bool, art::verifier::HardFailLogMode, unsigned int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>*)+492)
  #06  pc 0x0000000000192890  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::VerifyClass(art::Thread*, art::Handle<art::mirror::Class>, art::verifier::HardFailLogMode)+1460)
  #07  pc 0x00000000001958bc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::InitializeClass(art::Thread*, art::Handle<art::mirror::Class>, bool, bool)+356)
  #08  pc 0x0000000000180b8c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::EnsureInitialized(art::Thread*, art::Handle<art::mirror::Class>, bool, bool)+92)
  #09  pc 0x000000000030adcc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+532)
  #10  pc 0x0000000000305f98  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+892)
  #11  pc 0x00000000005aa104  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+372)
  #12  pc 0x0000000000131994  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20)
  #13  pc 0x000000000017e75a  /data/data/com.company.name/files/audience_network.dex (com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.89.A0E+126)
  #14  pc 0x00000000005aa3a0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+1040)
  #15  pc 0x0000000000131994  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20)
  #16  pc 0x000000000017e60e  /data/data/com.company.name/files/audience_network.dex (com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.89.A09+14)
  #17  pc 0x00000000002dc030  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.1012465689697948481)+240)
  #18  pc 0x0000000000598cc4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1032)
  #19  pc 0x0000000000140468  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88)
  #20  pc 0x00000000001375b8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568)
  #21  pc 0x0000000000169c78  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+276)
  #22  pc 0x000000000030ad38  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+384)
  #23  pc 0x0000000000305f98  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+892)
  #24  pc 0x00000000005aa104  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+372)
  #25  pc 0x0000000000131994  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20)
  #26  pc 0x0000000000166b00  /data/data/com.company.name/files/audience_network.dex (com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.5H.onContentProviderCreated+8)
  #27  pc 0x00000000005a9110  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1788)
  #28  pc 0x0000000000131a14  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface+20)
  #29  pc 0x00000000001664b4  /data/data/com.company.name/files/audience_network.dex (com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.5C.onContentProviderCreated+32)
  #30  pc 0x00000000002dc030  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.1012465689697948481)+240)
  #31  pc 0x0000000000598cc4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1032)
  #32  pc 0x0000000000140468  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88)
  #33  pc 0x00000000001a5590  /data/app/com.company.name-91DFwkqJ07GS7tkv8moMSA==/oat/arm64/base.odex (com.facebook.ads.internal.dynamicloading.DynamicLoaderFactory.doCallInitialize+464)
  #34  pc 0x00000000001a51a4  /data/app/com.company.name-91DFwkqJ07GS7tkv8moMSA==/oat/arm64/base.odex (com.facebook.ads.internal.dynamicloading.DynamicLoaderFactory$a.run+980)
  #35  pc 0x00000000001a51d8  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.lang.Thread.run+72)
  #36  pc 0x0000000000137334  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548)
  #37  pc 0x0000000000169c58  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+244)
  #38  pc 0x00000000004b74d0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)
  #39  pc 0x00000000004b85e4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue const*)+416)
  #40  pc 0x00000000004f91b8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1176)
  #41  pc 0x00000000000d4358  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
  #42  pc 0x0000000000071aa8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' // Required for Firebase
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' // Crashlytics
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.name"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 43
        versionName "4.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            firebaseCrashlytics {
                mappingFileUploadEnabled false
            }
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false //Keep All Strings in AAB file
        }
    }

    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-core'
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
    namespace 'com.company'

}

dependencies {

    // Defaults
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(path: ':library')

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.5.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10"

    // Firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.1.1') // BoM
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx' // Crashlytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics' // Analytics


    // AdMob
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.8'

    // Meta Audience Network
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.12.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:6.12.0.0'

    // Multidex
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    // Play Services
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0"

    // Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.14.2'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.14.2'
  
    // Timber
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'

    // Work Manager
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'

    // Material Dialogs
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:bottomsheets:3.3.0'

    // Commons Text
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.11'

    // Dagger Hilt
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.42'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.42'
    kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'

    // Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4'

    // DataStore
    implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0"

    // LiveData
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'

    // Fragment
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.5'

    // Lingver
    implementation "com.github.YarikSOffice:lingver:1.3.0"

}
```

[image: Play Console Crashes]

Comment: Have you solve this problem Mr. Amar?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the cause was that the ad sdk was being initialized by multiple processes.
The solution is to only initialize the advertising sdk in the main process.

Comment: I'm doing it only once in the Application class. But still the same issue