# artQuickToInterpreterBridge crash in Android 10

Tags: android-10.0, facebook-audience-network

I am experiencing a significant increase in crashes on Android 10 devices

Here's a sample crash log

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x000000000013181c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+28)
  #01  pc 0x00000000001edc88  /data/data/com.dubox.drive/files/audience_network.dex (com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Hg.A00+28)
  #02  pc 0x000000000059cdfc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+1168)
  #03  pc 0x0000000000131914  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20)
  #04  pc 0x00000000001ede16  /data/data/com.dubox.drive/files/audience_network.dex (com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Hg.A01+310)
  #05  pc 0x000000000059cdfc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+1168)
  #06  pc 0x0000000000131914  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20)
  #07  pc 0x00000000001eeaf4  /data/data/com.dubox.drive/files/audience_network.dex (com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Hg.A0J+284)
  #08  pc 0x000000000059aa6c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1432)
  #09  pc 0x0000000000131814  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20)
  #10  pc 0x00000000001ef364  /data/data/com.dubox.drive/files/audience_network.dex (com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Hn.A00+40)
  #11  pc 0x000000000059cdfc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+1168)
  #12  pc 0x0000000000131914  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20)
  #13  pc 0x00000000001ef626  /data/data/com.dubox.drive/files/audience_network.dex (com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Hn.doInBackground+22)
  #14  pc 0x00000000002b174c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.7142318256121416140)+240)
  #15  pc 0x000000000058bd64  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1012)
  #16  pc 0x0000000000140468  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88)
  #17  pc 0x000000000080260c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.AsyncTask$3.call+172)
  #18  pc 0x0000000000298d08  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run+200)
  #19  pc 0x00000000002fa878  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker+984)
  #20  pc 0x00000000002f7ee0  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run+64)
  #21  pc 0x00000000001a5568  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.lang.Thread.run+72)
  #22  pc 0x0000000000137334  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548)
  #23  pc 0x000000000014606c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+244)
  #24  pc 0x00000000004abd54  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)
  #25  pc 0x00000000004acde8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue const*)+416)
  #26  pc 0x00000000004ed17c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1176)
  #27  pc 0x00000000000e28c0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
  #28  pc 0x000000000008503c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
```

Audience Network 6.11.0

the same as [audience_network.dex com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.89.A0E - Crashes on Android 10 after adding Meta Audience Network mediation adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75168664/audience-network-dex-com-facebook-ads-redexgen-x-89-a0e-crashes-on-android-10#new-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, the reason is that the advertising sdk is initialized by multiple processes.